# \sqrt from another font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to change a specific char in my math collection: the square root symbol, as you can see below:

[image]

I'm trying to do it via `\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqrt}...` , but I can't determine witch parameters I have to enter.

The square root symbol that I want is available using the `utopia` option with the `mathdesign` package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to define new symbol fonts; the relevant declarations are

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdputsymbols}{OMS}{mdput}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdputlargesymbols}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n}    
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{mdputsymbols}{"70}{mdputlargesymbols}{"70}
```

Here's an example; the two `\let` instructions are to keep the old symbol for doing a comparison. In the output, the new one (Utopia based) is on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldsqrtsign\sqrtsign
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdputsymbols}{OMS}{mdput}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdputlargesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n}    
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{mdputsymbols}{"70}{mdputlargesymbols}{"70}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{abc}$
{\let\sqrtsign\oldsqrtsign$\sqrt{abc}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that this uses up two font alphabets (there are only 16 available), just for that symbol. It's not avoidable, as radicals need to be taken from a math font.