# sqrt upright style

Tags: math-mode

I need to change the style of sqrt and should make it a little bit narrower than the standard. second picture shows what I would like to have. any help is appreciated.

[image: this is what I already have]

[image: what I want to have]

Comment: You could change the font of the `\sqrt` to something better matching your expectations. Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63406/sqrt-from-another-font) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87440/how-can-i-standardize-my-square-root-signs)

Comment: With a little effort you could even draw it in TikZ.

Comment: Right. I draw the lines using TikZ but having problem about inserting the text in it.

Answer (score 2):

I took the following approach to solve this.  If I wanted  `\sqrt{expression}` where the surd was made narrow, I first expressed `\sqrt{\phantom{\cramped{#1#1}}}` and horizontally compressed it by a factor of 2.  I then overlaid, in a right-aligned format, the original `expression` overtop this squeezed-blank sqrt.

I used the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax of the `scalerel` package to import the current math style into the expression, so that it works in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, as well as `\displaystyle`.

The MWE shows expressions using the original `\sqrt`, and then the same expressions with the revised `\sqrt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel,mathtools}
\let\svsqrt\sqrt
\def\Sqrt#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{%
  \scalebox{.5}[1]{$\SavedStyle\svsqrt{\phantom{\cramped{#1#1}}}$}\cr
  \hfil$\SavedStyle\cramped{#1}$}}}
\parskip 1em
\def\testexpr{
  $\sqrt{2}\quad\sqrt{357x}\quad\scriptstyle\sqrt{12345}\quad\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}$
  \[\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\quad\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+1}}\]\par
}
\begin{document}
\centering
\testexpr
\let\sqrt\Sqrt
\testexpr
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one is concerned that compressing the expression by a factor of 2 makes the line thickness of the surd too thin, then this more complex definition provides a remedy:

```
\newsavebox\Nsqrt
\def\Sqrt#1{\ThisStyle{%
  \savebox\Nsqrt{\scalebox{.5}[1]{$\SavedStyle\svsqrt{\phantom{\cramped{#1#1}}}$}}%
  \ooalign{\usebox{\Nsqrt}\cr\kern.2pt\usebox{\Nsqrt}\cr\hfil$\SavedStyle\cramped{#1}$}}}
```

[image]

EDITED to insure that argument uses cramped math style (requires `mathtools` package).