# Introducing new version of a math symbol from another font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I'm trying to use a "hack" to get around the fact that `\mathsf` doesn't apply to lower-case Greek letters in math mode, by using the CM Bright font instead.  What I'd like to have is a command, for example, `\alphasf`, which calls the computer modern bright version of `\alpha` (which looks sort of sf-like).

To be clear, I do not want to change the behaviour of `\mathsf` itself, nor do I want `\alpha` to change.  I also do not want to use CM Bright anywhere else.

I'm trying to do this by defining a new math font (I realize there's only 16 but I don't think I'm going to hit that limit), using `\DeclareSymbolFont` (as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63406/sqrt-from-another-font)), and then using:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\alphasf}{** something with new font ** \alpha}
```

For what it's worth, I'm also loading the `amsmath` packages.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it for the `\alpha` and `\beta`, for example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{cmbright}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMB}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alphasf}{\mathalpha}{CMB}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\betasf}{\mathalpha}{CMB}{12}
\begin{document}
\[
AB\alpha\alphasf\beta\betasf
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]